# Passing kerberos keytab and principal in spark conf

Tags: apache-spark, kerberos

I am trying to run my spark application in local mode from within Intellij. The application reads a text file from hdfs using `sc.textFile("hdfs://...")`. The hdfs is secured by Kerberos authentication. I know you can use spark launcher and specify kerberos keytab and principal but for that I will have to do `sbt assembly` everytime I do a code change and want to test my chage. Is there an alternate/better way of specifying, kerberos keytab file and kerberos principal to spark? Also is there a parameter for providing the hdfs namenode information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you may provide these parameters when building your SparkSession ( [described here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/running-on-yarn.html#yarn-specific-kerberos-configuration)).

The second option is to pass principal and keytab as command-line arguments of your app.